# Change attribute using selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, html, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to change an attribute of a `WebElement` using Selenium Webdriver, but the code I'm using does not seem to work well.

I have this element on the web:

```
<div class="ui-slider-range ui-widget-header" 
     style="left: 23%; width: 33.00000000000001%;" ></div>
```

Suppose I have to change the style left value from 23% to 50%. And the same with the width attribute value from 33% to 75%. Then, the code I'm using to change the left attribute looks like this, but it keeps failing time by time:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) this.driver).executeScript("document.FindElementByClassName('ui-slider-range ui-widget-header').style.left=50%");
```

I did some research and I found that I should be using the `setAttribute` method inside the `executeScript` method, I tried that too but did not work as well.

Could you please give me some instructions here?

Comment: Isn't it `getElementsByClassName`? I think you're confusing the Selenium API with the DOM one.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I was able to solve this!